# Draw canvas on Rect with image and text

Tags: android, android-canvas

I've trying to create a `button` using `Rect`. I've created this successfully but my image and text is not properly on center. I want set in exact center but can't achieve. I need to do this by `Rect`. please guide me, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Here is my code snippet

```
RectF rightButton = new RectF(itemView.getRight() - 
buttonWidthWithoutPadding, itemView.getTop(), itemView.getRight(), itemView.getBottom());
    p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#F44336"));
    c.drawRoundRect(rightButton, corners, corners, p);
    drawView("DELETE", c, rightButton, p); 


//draw view method
private void drawView(String text, Canvas c, RectF button, Paint p) {
    float textSize = 20;
    p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setTextSize(textSize);

    float textWidth = p.measureText(text);
    Bitmap bmp = drawableToBitmap(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.delete_white_24dp));
    c.drawBitmap(bmp, button.centerX() - (bmp.getWidth() / 2), button.centerY() - (bmp.getHeight()/2), null);
    c.drawText(text, button.centerX() - (textWidth / 2), button.centerY() + bmp.getHeight(), p);
}
```

> Expected output

[image]

> My output (Not exactly in center also no space between image and text

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in drawView (instead of the last 2 lines):

```
float spaceHeight = 10; // change this to whatever looks good to you
Rect bounds = new Rect();
p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
float combinedHeight = bmp.getHeight() + spaceHeight + bounds.height();
c.drawBitmap(bmp, button.centerX() - (bmp.getWidth() / 2), button.centerY() - (combinedHeight / 2), null);
c.drawText(text, button.centerX() - (textWidth / 2), button.centerY() + (combinedHeight / 2), p);
```

You want the combination of icon+space+text centered, not just the icon. Right now the icon is perfectly in the middle and the text, due to being half as high as the icon, is exactly below it.

Comment: Adding spaceHeight as float will cause it look with different height on different screens right? Shouldn't we be using dp?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Maybe you're getting the numeric value type 'float' mixed up with the html/css property 'float'? This float is definitely not something that dynamically adjusts to screen size or anything else, it is defined as 10 (or whatever you choose to change that to) and will therefore simply add exactly 10 pixels between the picture and the text.

Comment: To clarify: the RectF button.centerY() returns a float, and the Canvas c.drawBitmap(...) takes a float (or an int, but not a double), so it's best to just use float for the other values you want to add together there.

Comment: Sources: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas